# Unity C# - Spawn objects at fixed points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Instead of making objects spawn at random range on the Y-axis like this:

`float y = Random.Range(1.723573f, 5.586497f)`;

How would I make objects spawn at 2 **fixed** locations on the Y-axis?

thank you

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve... You cannot simply choose 2 value for the y axis?

Comment: im trying to choose 2 static values for the Y axis instead of just 1 like float y = (1.723573f); but add an additional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you mean you want to spawn it either at one, or the other, then try this:

```
float y = Random.Range(0,100) > 50 ? 1.723573f : 5.586497f;
```

basically, there's a 50% chance of either the first value, or the second. You could alternatively type it out like this:

```
float y;

if(Random.Range(0,100) > 50)
   y = 1.723573f;
else y = 5.586497f;
```